# Adding a JSON Object under another JSON Object for Android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I want to create a JSON Structure like this:

```
{
"request": {
"slice": [
  {
    "origin": "BLR",
    "destination": "CCU",
    "date": "2015-06-18"
  }
],
"passengers": {
  "adultCount": 1,
  "infantInLapCount": 0,
  "infantInSeatCount": 0,
  "childCount": 0,
  "seniorCount": 0
},
"solutions": 20,
"refundable": false
}
}
```

For this I have written the following lines of code:

```
    JSONObject request_hdr = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray slice = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

    data.put("origin",Origin);
    data.put("destination",Destination);
    data.put("date", Start_Date);
    slice.put(data);
    request.put("slice",slice);
    request_hdr.put("request",request);

    JSONObject addl_info = new JSONObject();
    addl_info.put("adultCount",Num_Adult);
    addl_info.put("infantInLapCount",Num_Infant);
    addl_info.put("infantInSeatCount", 0);
    addl_info.put("childCount",0);
    addl_info.put("seniorCount",0);
    request.put("passengers",addl_info);
    request_hdr.put("request",request);

    JSONObject solutions = new JSONObject();
    solutions.put("solutions", 20);

    JSONObject refundable = new JSONObject();
    refundable.put("refundable","false");
```

I was not able to add the JSON objects 'solutions' and 'refundable' to the root object 'request'.

Can anybody please help me with this? Also I am not sure (i.e. never tested with parsing the JSON back) if the code wriiten above that works properly or not.

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you add `solutions` and `refundable` to `request` in this code? I see nothing on it.

Comment: `requests.put("solutions-key",solutionsObject)`

Comment: Yes I tried something..but it did not work...so I left it on you all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the end of your code,

```
JSONObject solutions = new JSONObject();
solutions.put("solutions", 20);

JSONObject refundable = new JSONObject();
refundable.put("refundable","false");
```

then the issue is you're never actually adding the objects to your `request`  object.

Also, those are values and not `JSONObjects`, so you should replace it with:

```
requests.put("solutions", 20);
requests.put("refundable", false);
```

if you want it to match the structure in your original post.

Comment: Thanks @Guardanis! It worked. :)
I understood now. The question was bit silly! :)